# What changes are made to non-system files when performing a System Restore? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, system-restore

I simply want to know what effect reverting a restore point via "System Restore" (Windows 7 64-bit) will have on non-system drives/partitions such as external hard drives and what (if any) deletions are made.

i.e. For example, I've configured a drive to restore system settings and previous versions of files, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Then I go to restore to a certain state, with those other drives included, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Will running the restore also delete any files/folders that were created on those partitions since the restore-point was made?

I googled around and on here but couldn't find a specific question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

The System Protection in Windows 7 works like the traditional System Restore but in addition hidden shadow copies of some of your own personal files are stored as well. Your personal information including folders like Documents, Pictures, Music, and backed up. System Protection could help you recover a file that was deleted or removed.